# resize iframes according to content

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to develop this site. I'm a beginner at javascript so I haven't actually figured out alot of codes as I've focused on html and css.

Is there a way that I can dynamically resize iframes but still have the scroll bars? Like if my iframe displays too many items then it would adjust to its content but not big enough for it to actually adjust the whole height of the page. I have this script that adjusts the iframe but I don't want it being too big if it had a lot to display.

```
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT : 
I just need the iframes to auto resize. It resizes but when the content has displayed a longer set of data, it doesn't go smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this CSS to display scroll in the page displayed by iframe.

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```